# CKEditor widgets forget they're widgets and become useless

Tags: javascript, widget, ckeditor

I have this CKEditor: http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/kwzcxrLj/ (no button image, the most right 3 buttons)

It adds widgets like this:

```
        // Add widget.
        editor.widgets.add('ezhealth_widget_' + size, {
            "template":
                '<div class="ezhealth-ckeditor-widget size-' + size + '">' +
                    '<h3 class="header editable">Title</h3>' +
                    '<div class="left"><p>Content</p></div>' +
                    '<div class="right"><p>Content</p></div>' +
                '</div>',
            "editables": {
                "header": {
                    "selector": '.editable',
                },
                "left": {
                    "selector": '.left',
                },
                "right": {
                    "selector": '.right',
                },
            },
            "allowedContent": 'div(!ezhealth-ckeditor-widget); h3(!header); div(!left); div(!right)',
        });
```

That works beautifully when you ADD a widget. But when you save the page and edit it, the widget becomes normal HTML. CKEditor doesn't know it's a widget. It doesn't have the normal edit constraints and styling that it does when it's new.

CKEditor's demo works fine: http://ckeditor.com/demo#widgets so it might be me.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define [`upcast`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.plugins.widget.definition-property-upcast) and [`downcast`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.plugins.widget.definition-property-downcast) callbacks of a widget definition which will let the Widget System know from what elements widgets of that type should be created and how widget of that type should be transformed into data.

```
editor.widgets.add( 'ezhealth_widget_' + size, {
    // ...

    upcast: function( element ) {
        return element.name == 'div'
            && element.hasClass( 'ezhealth-ckeditor-widget' )
            && element.hasClass( 'size-' + size );
    }
} );
```

Read more in the [How does a widget become a widget?](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/widget_sdk_tutorial_1-section-how-does-a-widget-become-a-widget%3F) section of the [Widget SDK](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/widget_sdk_intro).

Comment: I love you!! I missed that exact 1 paragraph and didn't read `Full Source Code` close enough. Thanks a billion. It ended up slightly different though: http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/kwzcxrLj/ `hasClass` didn't work... Even though `a = 'size-2575', b = 'ezhealth-ckeditor-widget size-2575 ezhealth_widget_2575', RegExp("(?:^|\\s)"+a+"(?=\\s|$)").test(b)` works fine.